# algorithm to find 'article' in webpage?

Tags: algorithm, html-content-extraction

some browser plugin, like [readability](http://readability.com/mobile/download) can extract the 'article' from a webpage. Does anyone has idea about how to do it? What's the difference between the real articles and ads or comments?

Comment: i guess you're mentioning about the news articles or kinda. each website has its own html structure showing articles, you have to create specific parser for each website to extract the articles. no super algorithm can do it all.

Comment: i dont think so. at least there is an open source article extractor: https://github.com/jiminoc/goose/wiki and i dont believe Readability implement thousands of parser

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends how you want to define "real articles"...

Taking HTML5 into consideration, a webpage is constructed of semantic tags. Pages no longer have to be built with elements like `<div>` that have exactly no semantic meaning. In HTML5 you may use `<section>`, `<article>`, `<header>`  [and so on](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_new_elements.asp). Those elements can give an application pretty good sense of what is the main content of a webpage (e.g. print `<article>`s and skip `<nav>`s...)

Of course, not many pages use those tags yet. Furthermore, the tags might get abused and lose their meaning. In that case I'd stick to some statistics, e.g. selecting the largest elements in a HTML document. Moreover, if you have to scrape a webpage, you could use a modification of some pattern-matching algorithm, DIPRE for instance.